# How to combine flags using RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-rewrite

I am using ISAPI-Rewrite on IIS7.
How can we combine [NC] and [OR] in a RewriteCond ?  [NC,OR] ?
What is the simple way to match domains with and without "www." ?

Here is a draft :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-one.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-one.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-two.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-two.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-website.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `[NC,OR]` is the way of combining those two flags.

To combine multiple **similar** conditions into one, try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(old-one\.com|www\.old-one\.com|old-two\.com|www\.old-two\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.new-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**P.S.**
Since you are on IIS 7, why not use their native rewriting engine (URL Rewrite module) -- yes, it has different syntax (not .Apache's .htaccess, but standard web.config XML file) but does work fine (no performance issues here on my servers).

Comment: Thank you ! Can the rewrite module be managed using a file (like .htaccess) or are we obliged to use IIS console ? (I don't want to be forced to ask operations to my hosting provider).

Comment: Yes -- all settings can be controlled via `web.config` file (unless IIS is instructed to keep those settings in a master config file only (for security reasons?) -- that is configurable (if you have full control over the server)).